# How to stop resize JavaScript code from being reset when broswer is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a responsive JS code that executes code based on a screen width. In my example code, it's set to run code when the screen size is under 801px.

The problem I'm having is when the screen size is under 801px. I refreshed the page and the code is reset as if the screen window is over 801px but still under 801px. It corrects itself when the screen window is moved.

Is there a way to fix this so that if the browser is refreshed, it doesn't reset?

This is my JS code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 801) {
    $(".mejs__currenttime-container,.mejs__duration-container").appendTo(".mejs__group-left");
    $(".mejs__time-rail").insertBefore(".mejs__group-left");
  } else {
    $(".mejs__currenttime-container,.mejs__duration-container").appendTo(".mejs__time-rail");
    $(".mejs__time-rail").insertBefore(".mejs__speed-button");
  }
}).resize();
```

EDIT: Here's a link to my problem http://wpfreelance.bayoumedia.net/audio/. You can see the problem when you move the browser under 801px, hit refresh and then move the browser 1px any direction.

Comment: _"I refreshed the page and the code is reset as if the screen window is over 801px but still under 801px"_ Is `resize` event handler called?

Comment: @guest271314 `}).resize();` so maybe

Comment: @Isaac Then not sure what issue is?

Comment: scrap that, im wrong. You could probably `}).trigger('resize')` or something

Comment: @Isaac Either should return same effect of `resize` event handler being called. The only difference between `if` and `else` appear to be `.appendTo(".mejs__group-left")`, `.insertBefore(".mejs__group-left")` and `.appendTo(".mejs__time-rail")`, `.insertBefore(".mejs__speed-button")`

Comment: @GregorySchultz  Can you create a stacksnippets or jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: don't use resize, use `matchMedia` and check as part of page initialization.

Comment: @zzzzBov can you provide an example?

Comment: @guest271314 question updated with link

Comment: @GregorySchultz Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co?

Comment: Cannot reproduce http://plnkr.co/edit/Qfq09uSQy7pVC8o3gDwm?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just move the code that is run when a resize occurs into it's own separate function. This function should be run when the page first loads, which "simulates" a resize immediately.

```
resizeWindow(); // call the function immediately when the page loads

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeWindow(); // also call the function when the page resizes
});

function resizeWindow() {
    if ($(window).width() < 801) {
        $(".mejs__currenttime-container,.mejs__duration-container").appendTo(".mejs__group-left");
        $(".mejs__time-rail").insertBefore(".mejs__group-left");
    } else {
        $(".mejs__currenttime-container,.mejs__duration-container").appendTo(".mejs__time-rail");
        $(".mejs__time-rail").insertBefore(".mejs__speed-button");
    }
}
```

Comment: `.resize()` does not call `resize` event handler?

Comment: @guest271314 Edited. I'm guessing the `.resize()` shouldn't have been there in OPs question?

Comment: _"I'm guessing the `.resize()` shouldn't have been there in OPs question? "_ ? How did you arrive at that conclusion? Alternative conclusions could be that code at OP is being called before `DOM` is loaded completely; or code at OP returns expected result. A minimal verifiable complete example by OP will resolve the inquiry.